# Use a list in a foreach loop

Tags: lists, foreach

I am trying to make a plot more automatic and I am trying to impose the presence of samples near point of interest.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{
    \gdef\alist{(\Wmin):}
    \foreach \i in {#2,#3} {
     \xdef\alist{\alist(0.5*1/\i),(0.5*1/\i):(2*1/\i),(2*1/\i):}
    }
    \xdef\alist{\alist(\Wmax)}
    \foreach \i in {(\Wmin):(0.5*1/#2),(0.5*1/#2):(2*1/#2),(2*1/#2):(0.5*1/#3),(0.5*1/#3):(2*1/#3),(2*1/#3):(\Wmax)}
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
        { 
            -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
            -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
        }[#4];
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [ymin=-90,ymax=80]
        \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
        \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the MWE, it works. But I wanted to replace

```
    \foreach \i in {(\Wmin):(0.5*1/#2),(0.5*1/#2):(2*1/#2),(2*1/#2):(0.5*1/#3),(0.5*1/#3):(2*1/#3),(2*1/#3):(\Wmax)}
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
```

by

```
    \foreach \i in {\alist}
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
```

But it doesn't compile. The list creation comes from a code I found here, and it seems like `\alist` contains the good thing but I can't seem to use it in the foreach.

I see two things you could do if you wish to help me :

- help me make the use of `\alist` work in `\foreach` (done)

  - answer 1 : change the expression `\foreach \i in {\alist}` to `\foreach \i in \alist`
  - answer 2 : use an array with `\usepackage{listofitems}` like so `\readlist\alistlst{\alist}%` `\foreachitem\i\in\alistlst[]{%`
- find a simple way to generate the sampling like with `samples at`

Thank you in advance.

If you are curious about the result :

[image: result of the plot]

Comment: What is the purpose of `\TracStack`'s 1st argument? (Seems `#1` doesn't occur in `\TracStack`'s definition.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit 1:

[pgfmanual.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#section.88) says about `\foreach`'s `⟨list⟩`-argument:

> Again, in the easiest case, `⟨list⟩`
> is either a comma-separated list of values surrounded by curly braces
> **or it is the name of a macro that contain such a list of values**. Anything can be used as a value, but numbers are most likely.

The phrase "name of a macro that contain such a list of values" is sort of misleading but that statement means:

If `⟨list⟩` is something that is **not** nested between a pair of curly braces, then `⟨list⟩` is taken for a control-sequence whose toplevel-expansion forms the comma-separated list of values in question.

Therefore all you need to do is omitting the curly braces that surround `\alist`:
Just change the expression `\foreach \i in {\alist}` to `\foreach \i in \alist`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{
    \gdef\alist{(\Wmin):}
    \foreach \i in {#2,#3} {
     \xdef\alist{\alist(0.5*1/\i),(0.5*1/\i):(2*1/\i),(2*1/\i):}
    }
    \xdef\alist{\alist(\Wmax)}
    \foreach \i in \alist % <- curly braces surrounding \alist are omitted here.
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
        { 
            -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
            -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
        }[#4];
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [ymin=-90,ymax=80]
        \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
        \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Previous answer:

One problem is that with `\foreach \i in {\alist}` the macro `\alist` is not expanded before `\foreach` is carried out.

Therefore `\foreach` won't take `\alist`'s expansion, i.e., the token-sequence `(\Wmin):(0.5*1/#2),(0.5*1/#2):(2*1/#2),(2*1/#2):(0.5*1/#3),(0.5*1/#3):(2*1/#3),(2*1/#3):(\Wmax)`  for its argument but will take the single token `\alist` for its argument.

You can apply `\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\alist}{\foreach...}`-trickery for having `\alist` expanded before having `\foreach` carried out:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{
    \gdef\alist{(\Wmin):}
    \foreach \i in {#2,#3} {
     \xdef\alist{\alist(0.5*1/\i),(0.5*1/\i):(2*1/\i),(2*1/\i):}
    }
    \xdef\alist{\alist(\Wmax)}
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\alist}{\foreach \i in }%
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
        { 
            -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
            -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
        }[#4];
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [ymin=-90,ymax=80]
        \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
        \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach: In case `\alist` is just a scratch-macro put `\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\i` inside the last `\xdef\alist`, and then call `\alist` instead of `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{
    \gdef\alist{(\Wmin):}
    \foreach \i in {#2,#3} {
     \xdef\alist{\alist(0.5*1/\i),(0.5*1/\i):(2*1/\i),(2*1/\i):}
    }
    \xdef\alist{\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\i in {\alist(\Wmax)}}
    \alist
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
        { 
            -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
            -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
        }[#4];
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [ymin=-90,ymax=80]
        \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
        \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and even more for the second Edition

Answer (score 4):

Define:

```
\def\foreachinlist#1#2{\expandafter\foreachinlistA\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}
\def\foreachinlistA#1{\foreach#1in}
```

and use:

```
\foreachinlist \i \alist
```

In your example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\def\foreachinlist#1#2{\expandafter\foreachinlistA\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}
\def\foreachinlistA#1{\foreach#1in}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{
    \gdef\alist{(\Wmin):}
    \foreach \i in {#2,#3} {
     \xdef\alist{\alist(0.5*1/\i),(0.5*1/\i):(2*1/\i),(2*1/\i):}
    }
    \xdef\alist{\alist(\Wmax)}
    \foreachinlist \i \alist
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
        { 
            -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
            -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
        }[#4];
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [ymin=-90,ymax=80]
        \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
        \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a little help from `listofitems`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,listofitems}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{
    \gdef\alist{(\Wmin):}
    \foreach \i in {#2,#3} {
     \xdef\alist{\alist(0.5*1/\i),(0.5*1/\i):(2*1/\i),(2*1/\i):}
    }
    \xdef\alist{\alist(\Wmax)}
    \readlist\alistlst{\alist}% <-- READS \alist ITEMS INTO \alistlst LIST
    \foreachitem\i\in\alistlst[]{% <-- OPERATES ON SUCCESSIVE \alistlst ITEMS
        \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
        { 
            -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
            -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
        }[#4];
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [ymin=-90,ymax=80]
        \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
        \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it answers my first point, even if I don't quite grasp the differences between `\alist` and `\alistlst`

Comment: @LMT-PhD `\alist` is just a string filled with commas and data, whereas `\alistlst` is an array of separate elements.  For example, the second element of the array is `\alistlst[2]`, the fourth, `\alistlst[4]`, which can be accessed independently.  The `\foreachitem` syntax of the `listofitems` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems) provides the syntax to successively access each item of the list array.

Comment: @LMT-PhD It seems the `samples at` data need not be looped.  So, for example, if you can create a def, such as `\def\z{.1, .2, .4, .8, 1.6, 3.2, 6.4, 12.8, 25.6, 51.2, 100}`, then you can directly use `\addplot [domain=\i,samples at=\z]{...}`.  Or are you asking how to create a sample for `\alist`?

Comment: For `samples at` I'd like to be able generate the values to sample around the points of interest, in my example I impose more samples between X/2 and X*2 for each X of interest. But the values of Xs can change, and what happens if X*2 > X'/2, there might be an overlap.

Comment: @LMT-PhD I don't do enough pgf/tikz work to fully grasp how to achieve your goal.  But I would say this: if your axis is logarithmic, so should your samples, which is why, in my prior comment regarding `\z`, each sample point was based on a ratio to the prior value, rather than a delta from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all the `\xdef` business.

Here the name `\foreachiinlist` is completely arbitrary and its meaning will disappear as soon as the macro is executed. So you will have no `\alist` in the way any longer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand{\TracStackPoints}[1]{(0.5*1/#1),(0.5*1/#1):(2*1/#1),(2*1/#1):}

\newcommand*{\TracStack}[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\foreachiinlist{%
    \endgroup
    \unexpanded{\foreach \i in }%
    {(\Wmin):\TracStackPoints{#2}\TracStackPoints{#3}(\Wmax)}%
  }%
  \foreachiinlist {
    \addplot [domain=\i,samples=50]
      { 
       -(10*(log10(#2^2*x^2+1)))
       -(10*(log10(#3^2*x^2+1)))
      }[#4];
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
  \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[ymin=-90,ymax=80]
    \TracStack{10}{10}{0.1}{}
    \TracStack{100}{5}{0.2}{red}
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]